# LaTeX notation leading to error "You may need to add $ $ around a certain inline R expression `r `" when knitting pdf_document

Tags: r-markdown, knitr, pdflatex

I try to knit R markdown document with mathematic notation (code in Latex) because it's very useful in my study but an error constantly appear when I knit it.

For example:

```
    ---
title: "fiche"
author: "chin38"
date: "18/01/2021"
output: pdf_document
---


Erreur$^2 = E_D[(q(D)- p)^2]=E_D[(q(D)-\overline{q}+\overline{q}-p)^2]=(\overline{q}-p)^2+E_D[(q(D)-\overline{q})^2]$
= Biais$^2$ + Variance

Biais = $E_D[q(D)]- p$
Variance = $Var_D[q(D)]$
$ = E_D[(q(D)-\overline{q})^2]$
```

here is the error message:

```
! Missing $ inserted. <inserted text> 
                $ l.74 E\_D{[}(q(D)-\overline{q}
                              )\^{}2{]}\$ 

Try to find the following text in fiche.Rmd:   E\_D{[}(q(D)-\overline{q} 

You may need to add $ $ around a certain inline R expression `r ` in fiche.Rmd (see the above hint). See https://github.com/rstudio/rmarkdown/issues/385 for more info. Erreur : LaTeX failed to compile fiche.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See fiche.log for more info. Exécution arrêtée
```

So, I follow the instruction in the link above but I still have the problem. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the function [cat](http://rfunction.com/archives/1866) inside an R chunk, you get your mathematical notation.

Important notes:

- you have to set the `{r results='asis'}` as in the example below. About this option:

> asis: Write text output as-is, i.e., write the raw text results directly into the output document without any markups.

You can read more about chunk options [here](https://yihui.org/knitr/options/#code-evaluation).

- You need double backslash before `overline`
- You start and end your notation with `$`

  ````
  ---
  title: "fiche"
  author: "chin38"
  date: "18/01/2021"
  output: pdf_document
  ---

  Your result 


  ```{r results='asis', echo=FALSE}

  part1 <- cat("$Erreur^2 = E_D[(q(D)- p)^2]$")
  part2 <- cat("$E_D[(q(D)-\\overline{q}+\\overline{q}-p)^2]$")
  part3 <- cat("$\\overline{q}-p)^2+E_D[(q(D)-\\overline{q})^2]$")


  ```
  ````

[image]